# Start lots of background jobs but keep their logs separated

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have little experiences in shell commands in unix.
So far, I have checked stackOverflow and know how to run simple shell scripts in order by

1. using echo

```
echo $(sh dosomthing1.sh)
echo $(sh dosomthing2.sh)
```

2. directly using sh xxx and wait

```
sh dosomthing1.sh
wait 
sh dosomthing2.sh
```

3. using &&

```
sh dosomthing1.sh && sh dosomthing2.sh
```

But these ways seem to be helpless to solve my problem...

Here is my problem:

I have a basic shell script to do a maven compile and then using "nohup xxx &" to start a java application in background. the script is shown below:

```
#get the input env parameter
env=$1

#goto application root directory
cd /applicationDir

#to compile
mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true

#to start with parameter env
nohup java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=$env myApplication.jar &

#to tail the log
tail -20f myApplication.log
```

I have too many different applications with the same startup scripts and it is hard to start them one by one. I need to start them with one command.

All the shell scripts are expected to be processed one by one in order. If there are any exceptions, skip  and run the next one.

And when I tried to write a script like this:

```
sh start1.sh
wait
echo "application 1 was start up"

sh start2.sh
wait
echo "application 2 was start up"

...

sh startxxx.sh
wait
echo "application xxx was start up"
```

Though all the children shell scripts will process in order as what I expected, and the output infomations looked like the shell is functioning well, but the fact is only the last application will be started, all the previous command "nohup xxxx &" will be shut down.

Also I have tried to write like this:

```
sh start1.sh &

sh start2.sh &

...

sh startxxx.sh &
```

Although the result was what I want, all the application will be started well, but during processing the scripts, because of the parallel running of the scripts, the consoled output is unreadable. It comes to a good result but not a graceful way.

I have no idea how to solve this problem...

Please help me with this, thank you very much!

Comment: What's the point of `wait`? It only waits for background jobs. You have no background jobs

Comment: Also, `echo $(anything)` is basically always worse than just running `anything` on its own.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I'm new to write shell scripts. I didn't read much documentations ,just copy them from google...While I still have no idea how to run these children scripts in order. If I just run them on their own one by one, the script happens to stuck at the first child's command "nohup xxxxx &" @CharlesDuffy

Answer (score 1):

When you have a script with commands, you cam do `chmod +x start.sh`. Now the script can be started with `./start.sh`. You will avoid an additional `sh` process and with `ls -l` you can see which scripts are executable.
In your scripts you have `tail -f`. This will be very confusing for a backgound process. Start the scripts in the background and view the logging from the console. I do hope that each script is using a different `myApplication.jar` and `myApplication.log`.
When the logging in the logfile is duplicated in stdout (your commandline window), you can throw that logging away.

```
./start1.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
./start2.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
./startxxx.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

The processes will be killed when you logout before the scripts are terminated. This can be avoided with `nohup`:

```
nohup ./start1.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
nohup ./start2.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
nohup ./startxxx.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Edit:
OPS wants to start programs in a fixed order.
Starting scripts exactly one after another in order, should be possible by calling them in the right order (perhaps with an additional `sleep 1`).
When you need to wait for program 1 finished some init stuff, you need to check that. Use 1 script calling all scripts and add some control statements, like

```
nohup java something &
while ! grep -q "Started" myApplication.log; do 
   sleep 1
done
```

When the java program has an error the `while` will wait for ever, so replace this with some max retrycount

```
for ((retry=0l retry<100; retry++)); do
   grep -q "Started" myApplication.log && break
   sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm confused about. At the very beginning I prefer the second method using nohup to call children scripts to start applications. The actual startup commands are in children scripts and each of them works in a proper way on their own. But when I'm trying to start them exactly one after another in order, it won't work unless I use "sh xxxx &" . The second method you mentioned will not work, only the last application will be started. Is that the "tail -f" command in children scripts that leaded to the previous applications been shut down?

Comment: I see no reason why a previous are shut down by starting a new one. Perhaps you used CTRL-C trying to kill a `tail` or `wait`? When all programs write to the some logfile, this might be a problem: When they don't append but create a logfile, a running program writing to the original file can't write anything anymore.

Answer (score 0):

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cron.8.html

This might help you.  Cron is a task scheduler, which you can use to run programs in sequence.  If the man page is difficult to understand, look for tutorials on it; I'm sure some would exist.

Comment: Thanks again! After reading this man page, I think it solved me another question: to restart all applications after the server reboot and I marked it into my notebook. But I think it would be a little complicated using crond in this case. I have application based scheduler which can process my commands too, but I still wonder if there is a more easeier way. This script will be used only in my dev server, it may be used frequently to restart all applications after new commitment of code to having a test.

Comment: Although it Might be easy to write a new script to restart them without calling children scripts. It may lead to too many hard codes. So I still prefer to write it in a simple way, call children scripts one by one in a new shell script, if there are some changes, I can just comment out single line then rerun the shell script.

Comment: @william, there are other tools that are appropriate to use to start background processes on boot, check if they're up, restart them when needed, etc. This category is called "process supervision tools", and cron is not one. Your operating system will come with a process supervisor -- if it's MacOS, that tool is launchd, and it's controlled with launchctl; if it's a reasonably mainstream Linux distro, it's probably using systemd. Either way, nobody should be writing shell scripts or using cron for this purpose in 2021 -- if you want a program to run on boot, configure your supervisor to do it.

Comment: @william, ...also, modern process supervision tools take care of managing your program's log output for you. `journalctl -b -u program1` (on systemd-based systems that use journald to manage logs) will show you only the logs since boot of program1, for example.

Comment: @william, ...another thing about process supervisors is that you can configure the better ones with rules. "Always wait until program-1 has finished startup before starting program-2"; "After program-1 fails with an error, run script-A to send an email; only restart it if it hasn't had more than 3 errors in the last 5 minutes"; etc. "Wait for at least one network interface to be up to configure before starting program-3, and shut it down if that network goes away".

Comment: @petrus4, ...if the question could be fully and canonically answered with the advice "use cron", we would want to mark the question as a duplicate, because that answer has given before to many, many other similar questions. Note the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and the bullet point regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy well, in this case I need this shell to do more likely as a composed shell script. While each of the application has it's own startup shell script, this shell script is to call those startup scripts one by one. I still have that question why the previous scripts will be shut down by directly using sh xxx.sh to start a child script.